# Check mailflow for Microsoft SMTP service

Tags: c#, .net, email, powershell, smtp

We have a SMTP Cluster (Microsoft SMTP Service) that we would like to check for mailflow every 5 minutes.

What we would like is to send a mail every 5 minutes through every node to a mailbox - check the mailbox for received mails and see how long it took.

We would like to use Powershell to do the sendmail function and we got that in place.
Our obstacle is how to read mails automatically? We have tested that we could use Gmail as receiving mailbox and can read mails through Powershell (Feeds / Atom) but that doesn't mark the mails as read in the mailbox.

We have own Hosted Exchange, maybe we could use that for receiving mail?

Any thoughts?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Exchange mailboxes available, you can script reading and manipulating email (including marking as Read) with Powershell using the EWS managed api:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(v=EXCHG.80).aspx

Glen Scales has many good articles and code samples for using it on his blog:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(v=EXCHG.80).aspx